# Setting a function to call multiple functions using triggers in Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to call functions `callingA`, `callingB` and `callingC` using trigger "`MultipleFunctiontr`" one after other in sequence

1. Creating a trigger for multiple function tr
2. Calling above 3 functions one after other

```js
    function callingA(){
    //Some code
    }
    function callingB(){
    //Some Code
    }
    function callingc(){
    //Some code
    }

    function multipleFunctionTr(){
    deletetr(multipleFunctionTr);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    createTrigger();  
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Basically, I want to call multiple functions using triggers.Here the functions are callingA,CallingB and callingC

Answer (score 2):

A trigger can only call one function. If you want to call the three functions, create a separate function that will call all three.

For example, if you want to execute `callingA()`, `callingB()`, and `callingC()` every 6 hours, you could write this:

```js
function multipleFunctionTr() {
  callingA();
  callingB();
  callingC();
}

function callingA() { /* do something */ }

function callingB() { /* do something */ }

function callingC() { /* do something */ }
```

Then [manually install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) a trigger that calls `multipleFunctionTr()`.

You could also install it programmatically. Running this function would create a trigger to make it run every 6 hours (adapted from [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)).

```
/**
 * Execute multipleFunctionTr() every 6 hours.
 */
function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('multipleFunctionTr')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();
}
```

Comment: I have created triggers for all three functions but I want them to execute in order callingA(),callingB() and callingC() immediately after each trigger finished execution

Comment: @user8735885 What exactly is the difference between having 3 different triggers and doing it the way I suggested? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user8735885 The code in my answer executes callingA(), callingB(), and callingC() in order.